# Apple Watch 2/FaceTime is possibly hacked?

Tags: apple-watch, facetime

I received what appears to be a malicious message on my Apple Watch 2.  It did not arrive via any known messaging app.  There was no banner, only the words.  The words were threatening. I had recently been using FaceTime.  I checked my iPad and iPhone but theres no message there.  Then I went on my MacBook Air and a box popped up: "Your Apple ID and phone number are now being used for FaceTime on a new Apple Watch".  My Apple Watch is not a new Apple Watch. so I'm a bit alarmed.  Any advice?

Comment: This commonly happens after updating devices. I wouldn't sweat it.

Comment: A threatening message arrives after an update? In truth the watch was updated yesterday.

Comment: How did the sender know I was on FaceTime? and whats the significance of the message about FaceTime being used on my Apple Watch 2?  My watch doesn't have this app.

Answer (score 1):

That is not any threat. I think you signed into FaceTime on your Apple Watch using your Apple ID. So all your other apple devices will notify you. But your device doesn't know whether your Apple Watch is new or old. Even I got that message on my MacBook after signing in into FaceTime on my iPad. It is not a threatening message!

Comment: The message on my watch, which didn’t arrive under the banner of any known messaging app supported on the watch or iPhone or iPad was threatening. It said I should watch myself, and ended with the words “This is not about me, Iceman, it’s about you”.

Comment: @Iceman please add this information to your question. It may be useful to these offering answers. Cheers